# How can I get around this pycparser installation error using poetry?

Tags: python-3.6, python-poetry, pycparser

I'm using the latest version of poetry (1.1.10) and while trying to update my lock file, I ran into an error while attempting to install pycparser==2.20:

```
Writing lock file

Package operations: 65 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing pycparser (2.20)

  ValueError

  File \C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\artifacts\3b\b4\2e\87ea123a592747e6f6c798c66837974694db0bca4783357f71718a538d\pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl does not exist

  at c:\users\boris\miniconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\poetry\core\packages\file_dependency.py:40 in __init__
       36│             except FileNotFoundError:
       37│                 raise ValueError("Directory {} does not exist".format(self._path))
       38│
       39│         if not self._full_path.exists():
    →  40│             raise ValueError("File {} does not exist".format(self._path))
       41│
       42│         if self._full_path.is_dir():
       43│             raise ValueError("{} is a directory, expected a file".format(self._path))
```

I tried changing my poetry version as well as that of pycparser, but that only seems to break other packages. Has anyone dealt with this before, and if so can you point me in the right direction?

Specs:
OS: Windows 10
Python version: 3.6
poetry==1.1.10
pycparser==2.20

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue which was resolved by deleting the Poetry cache folder: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. I cleared the cash by listing all cache names `poetry cache list` and then by deleting needed ones `poetry cache clear *cache_name* --all`. Afterwards installation completed successfully